# Do you have to close a cursor in a T-SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We're getting intermittent problems with PayPal orders and I've been digging into our code. We're getting an exception which says "The wait operation timed out" in a particular stored procedure. In the stored procedure I can see that a cursor called `item_cursor` is declared and later opened but it is never closed. The stored procedure simply ends without ever calling `close item_cursor` (or `DEALLOCATE item_cursor`).

I'm a front-end dev rather than back-end so I'm a little out of my depth but could this be causing the problem?

Comment: most of the time `The wait operation timed out` error occurs when your query is not good enough..I dont see any issues with leaving a cursor open,unless,it is a global cursor(though it is best practice to close cursor after usage

Comment: try updating statistics and run the query again,also post your query along with execution plan,schema,count ..better an MVCE

Comment: Is the timeout on the web side? Maybe your SP just takes too long and hits a timeout (usually 30 seconds). Sometimes you can rewrite a cursor as a set based operation and that improves performance considerably

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how the [cursor is declared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms180169.aspx):

> LOCAL
>
> Specifies that the scope of the cursor is local to the batch, stored procedure, or trigger in which the cursor was created. The cursor name is only valid within this scope. ... *The cursor is implicitly deallocated when the batch, stored procedure, or trigger terminates*, unless the cursor was passed back in an OUTPUT parameter. If it is passed back in an OUTPUT parameter, the cursor is deallocated when the last variable referencing it is deallocated or goes out of scope.
>
> GLOBAL
>
> Specifies that the scope of the cursor is global to the connection. The cursor name can be referenced in any stored procedure or batch executed by the connection. *The cursor is only implicitly deallocated at disconnect*.

(My *emphasis*)

It then goes on to explain how it chooses a default if neither is specified, but if you've not changed anything else on your system, it will be `GLOBAL` by default, which in this case means that, yes, it will be "leaking". If the cursor is holding any locks it will continue to hold those locks until your connection is disconnected.